# I'm trying to display data from a MySQL database onto an HTML table but doesn't register the column fields

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am new to PHP coding and don't understand where I have gone wrong, I'm trying to display data from a MySQL database onto an HTML table but doesn't register the column fields, keeps coming up with Notice: Undefined index: First, Notice: Undefined index: last etc. How do I define my column fields?

Edited: here are links to pictures of my database and the error codes I'm receiving: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjY05.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aA96b.jpg

Here is my code:

```
</head>
```

```
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'form_database') or die("Can not connect: " . mysqli_error());

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT first, last, phone, class FROM form_submissions");

echo "<table border=1>
<tr>
<th>First Name</th>
<th>Last Name</th>
<th>Phone Number</th>
<th>Class interested in</th>
</tr>"; 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . $row['first'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['last'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . $row['class'] . "</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);

?>
</body>
```

Comment: I guess  you just need to replace `mysqli_fetch_array` with `mysqli_fetch_assoc`  http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php  **Note: Field names returned by this function are case-sensitive.**

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139035/discussion-on-question-by-sam-smith-im-trying-to-display-data-from-a-mysql-datab).

Answer (score 1):

check if you do have results before displaying, them.

```
<?php
// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'form_database');
// Check connection
if (!$con) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql    = "SELECT * FROM form_submissions";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

//check if you get any results
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    echo "<table border=1>
        <tr>
        <th>First Name</th>
        <th>Last Name</th>
        <th>Phone Number</th>
        <th>Class interested in</th>
        </tr>";

    // output data of each row
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['first'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['last'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['phone'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['class'] . "</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
} else {
    echo "No results found";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```